# How Can I config properly cloudinary in laravel 10?

Tags: php, laravel, cloudinary

Cloudinary is getting undefined. I am using laravel 10 and "cloudinary-labs/cloudinary-laravel": "^2.0",

I have installed cloudinary by

`composer require cloudinary-labs/cloudinary-laravel`

And publish cloudinary configuration by

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="CloudinaryLabs\CloudinaryLaravel\CloudinaryServiceProvider"
```

and add in config/api.php

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    CloudinaryLabs\CloudinaryLaravel\CloudinaryServiceProvider::class,
],

'aliases' => [
    ...
    'Cloudinary' => CloudinaryLabs\CloudinaryLaravel\Facades\Cloudinary::class,
],
```

also provided my api key, cloud name in .env file.

And this is my controller

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use CloudinaryLabs\CloudinaryLaravel\Facades\Cloudinary;
 
    class FileUploadController extends Controller
    {
        public function storeUploads(Request $request)
        {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        if($image){
            $cloudinary = new Cloudinary();
        }
        
    }
}
```

Here is I am getting undefined Cloudinary

Comment: also I have tried 

use CloudinaryLabs\CloudinaryLaravel\Cloudinary;

Comment: `CloudinaryLabs\CloudinaryLaravel\Facades\Cloudinary` is a facade so you shouldn't need to do `new` to it you just use it e.g. `CloudinaryLabs\CloudinaryLaravel\Facades\Cloudinary::upload($image)`

Comment: I have tried also without new keyword but not work

Comment: Facades do not get instantiated, they are used to provide static methods for convenience purposes. Also, the documentation states you should not be performing most of those install steps for a Laravel 10 platform.

Comment: And... you are not "getting undefined Cloudinary". You are getting a full error message and stack trace, which you have decided not to share with us.

Comment: <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use CloudinaryLabs\CloudinaryLaravel\Facades\Cloudinary;

class FileUploadController extends Controller
{
    public function storeUploads(Request $request)
    {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $cloudinary = Cloudinary::upload($image->getRealPath());
        $imageUrl = $cloudinary->getSecurePath();
        return response(['url' => $imageUrl]);
    }
}


this is correct?

Comment: I am getting error in network tab

message
: 
"Call to a member function getRealPath() on null"

Comment: i would recommend going over https://github.com/cloudinary-devs/cloudinary-laravel#installation again to see if you missed anything

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. My issue was the cache. When I restart the IDE it's working.